# R highcharts color specific column on chart

Tags: r, highcharts, colors, categories

I am trying to assign different colors to my column chart based on value group on xaxis. But I could not figure it out. Please see the picture for what I want. Is there a way to do it in highcharter R package?

Say 0-20 in blue, 21-40 in red, 41-60 in green.
Thank you very much!

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
weeks <- 96
nx <- 3
ny <- 20
df<-data.frame(rep(seq(24,weeks,24), each = nx * ny), xVar = rep(1:nx, times = weeks/24* ny),zVar=rep(runif(20,min=c(0), max=c(1)),times=4*3),
               w1=rep(seq(1,4,1), each = nx * ny))
colnames(df)<-c('weeks','treatment', 'val','w1')
df<-df[order(df$weeks,df$treatment, df$val),]
df$valF<-NULL
df$valF<-df$val*df$w1*df$treatment*-1
df$valF[1:5]<-df$valF[1:5]*-1
df<-df[order(df$weeks,df$treatment, -df$valF),]
yVar<-rep(1:ny,times=weeks/24*nx)
yVar
df<-cbind(df,yVar)
df$yVar<-as.factor(df$yVar)
library(reshape2)
library(highcharter)
df$valF<-round(df$valF,2)
wide<-dcast(df, treatment+yVar~weeks, value.var="valF" )
colnames(wide)<-c('treatment', 'yVar','w24', 'w48','w72','w96')


for (i in 1:60){wide$value1[i]=list(list(sequence = c(wide$w24[i],wide$w48[i],wide$w72[i],wide$w96[i]
)))}

for (i in 1:60){wide$value2[i]=list(list(sequence = c(wide$w24[i],wide$w48[i],wide$w72[i],wide$w96[i]
)))}

for (i in 1:60){wide$value3[i]=list(list(sequence = c(wide$w24[i],wide$w48[i],wide$w72[i],wide$w96[i]
)))}

for (i in 1: 60) {wide$w24[i]<-wide$w24[i]-0.5}
for (i in 1: 60) {wide$w48[i]<-wide$w48[i]-0.5}
for (i in 1: 60) {wide$w72[i]<-wide$w72[i]-0.5}
for (i in 1: 60) {wide$w96[i]<-wide$w96[i]-0.5}

wide$w24[c(1,3,5,7,8,20,30, 35,40,50)]=NA
wide$w48[c(1,3,6,7,8,20,32, 37,40,52)]=NA
wide$w72[c(1,3,9,4,8,20,29,30,36,40,53)]=NA
wide$w96[c(1,3,5,15,8,20,26,28,31,35,40,55)]=NA

for (i in 1:60){wide$valuePoint[i]=list(list(sequence = c(wide$w24[i],wide$w48[i],wide$w72[i],wide$w96[i]
)))}
highchart() %>%
   hc_yAxis(max =1, min = -13)%>%
    hc_add_series(data = wide$valuePoint[1:60], type = "scatter",name="n1",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="black")%>%
   
     hc_add_series(data = wide$value1[1:60], type = "column", name="n2",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="skyblue")%>%
       hc_motion(enabled = TRUE,
            labels = c("week24", "week48","week72","week96"),
            series = c(0,1))
```

What I can create is quite different from this code

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis(max =1, min = -12)%>%
  #hc_xAxis(categories = categories_grouped) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = wide$value[1:20], type = "column",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="skyblue")%>%
  hc_add_series(data = wide$value[21:40], type = "column",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="blue")%>%
  hc_add_series(data = wide$value[41:60], type = "column",  showInLegend = FALSE, color="red")%>%
    hc_motion(enabled = TRUE,
            labels = c("week24", "week48","week72","week96"),
            series = c(0,1,2))
```

Thank you very much!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities, e.g. you can create a custom JS logic for this in R:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "column",
    data = list(5, 4, 3)
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
        const chart = this;
        chart.series[0].data.forEach(function(point) {
          if (point.y <= 3) {
            point.update({
              color: 'red'
            })
          }

          if (point.y > 3 && point.y <= 4) {
            point.update({
              color: 'green'
            })
          }
        });
      }
    ")
  ))
```

You can learn more about how to do it here:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR1D8zc_yAVQRoI5eEBKkJJcW0g7liTv7hfuS4-2uCPg7cC6l_QXwCh4QXw

You can also try using dedicated options from the Highcharts API such as column.zones:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.zones

Comment: Thank you very much!